# MainView visibility on .inactive ScenePhase

Tags: authentication, swiftui

On my iOS app I use the typical way for biometric authentication after coming back from background:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
  @Environment(\.scenePhase) var phase

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      MainView()

      .onChange(of: phase) { (newPhase) in
          switch newPhase {
          case .active: 
              biometricsAuthentication()
          case .inactive: print("App is inactive")
          case .background: print("App is on background")
              appBlocked = true
          default: print("default")
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Doing this way everything works OK, but there is a little moment MainView is visible BEFORE authentication method triggers, I supossed due to the fraction of time that app is .inactive, after coming back from .background.

On MacOS app version, I call this authentication method on AppDelegate "applicationDidFinishLaunching" method, and nothing at all is presented until authentication finishes. So, I've tried to emulate this on iOS, with a dedicated AppDelegate, and trying some methods, without success.

Is this the correct way of doing it? Is there a way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the MainView is drawn, before the state value changes for your phase. You need to separate the two views such that the Main and Auth are not presented until the authentication check is logically checked. However, you'll need something to show for the Async nature of it. If you force it to show the Auth view, when the user is already logged in, then the auth view will also appear briefly. The thing I do is to add a "Loading" view or a "Splash" view which is the starting view, and is changed to the others depending on the returned check value for auth or main. Here is a potential solution. You'll want to handle for when you actually want the MainView to be shown.

```
struct AuthenticationView: View {
    @Binding var isAuthenticated: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if isAuthenticated {
                MainView()
            } else {
                // Blank view or maybe a splash screen
                Color.clear
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            biometricsAuthentication()
        })
    }

    func biometricsAuthentication() {
        // Do the biometrics check
        // If authentication is successful, set isAuthenticated to true
        // isAuthenticated = true
    }
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @State private var isAuthenticated = false
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var phase

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            AuthenticationView(isAuthenticated: $isAuthenticated)

            .onChange(of: phase) { (newPhase) in
                switch newPhase {
                case .active:
                    if !isAuthenticated {
                        // Trigger authentication again, in case it failed earlier
                        biometricsAuthentication()
                    }
                case .inactive, .background:
                    isAuthenticated = false
                default: break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In truth there are a bunch of different ways to handle this, but I do think this is probably the most common way of handling it.

Comment: Thanks. I supposed it must be something that kind. So the key is to insert MainView()  inside LoginView() or other AuthenticationView(), and not the other way round.

Comment: Just another question, @xTwisteDx. As MainView and ColorView are exclusive, there is no way to generate any kind of transition beethween them? I'm trying with oppacity and so, without getting the way.

Comment: @arroyot24 all you'll need to do is tie your boolean value to a local `@State` and change that state value `onChange` with the `withAnimation`. Then any `withAnimation(...)` or `.transition(...)` should take effect. So if you want a transition, then you'll need to make sure to set some @State for just that transition.

Comment: The problem, @xTwisteDx, with your approach is that authentication method:

Comment: @arroyot24 can you be more descriptive? I use this same approach in a production app today, not entirely sure I follow. Happy to take a look and provide additional clarification if you're still stuck on this.

Comment: Solved! Just a problem of mine. Variables placed on wrong place. Now, it is working, ok. Thanks!